# How are app reviews handled in the iPhone/Android/Blackberry app stores

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry

I am considering writing a mobile application for one of the following mobile platforms:

- iPhone
- Android
- Blackberry

One area which I am struggling to get more information about is how app reviews are handled in the app stores on these platforms. In particular, I am trying to answer the following questions:

- Are app reviews moderated for spam/offensive language?
- Are app reviews ever "aged"? This could mean discarding old reviews or weighting them lower when calculating an average rating.
- Does publishing a new version of the app cause old reviews to be discarded?

Comment: I now have 3 great answers for the 3 platforms I asked about. Which should I accept? I have upvoted all the answers for now.

Comment: The android answer came first so I'm going to mark that as accepted so that one of you gets the reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can help out with the **Android** side of things:

- Reviews are not actively monitored, however there is a report button next to each comment which can be used to mark it as spam or whatever.
- Newer reviews are placed at the top.
- Pushing a new version does not get rid of the old reviews.

Answer (score 3):

on **iPhone**

- Reviews don't appear immediately and
  I've never seen any that constitute
  spam or contain offensive language so
  I assume they are moderated.
- Newer reviews are placed at the top, I don't know how the average is calculated.
- Reviews for the most recent version
  are shown by default but you can
  chose to read reviews for all
  versions.

Answer (score 2):

on **BlackBerry App World**

- Reviews appear immediately (though there is extensive caching for the mobile client / delivery infrastructure so you may see reviews on the website before the App World client)
- Newer reviews are placed at the top
- Pushing a new version does not get rid of the old reviews
- There's regular expression searching for offensive comments (which results in funny situations - we had a review flagged because it contained the word 'button' which contained the word 'butt')
- In the vendor portal, you can flag reviews for your apps as unfair/offensive at which point the App World team will take a look and maybe remove them

Other BlackBerry app stores are a bit different